# Protocol not visible

Tags: objective-c

In FeedbackTarget.h:

```
@protocol FeedbackTarget <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, retain) Feedback *feedback;
- (void)someMethod;
@end
```

In FeedbackViewControllerTests.m:

```
#import "FeedbackTarget.h"
...
- (void)setUp
{
  [super setUp];
  self.feedbackTarget = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:FeedbackTarget];
}
```

Why do I get the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'FeedbackTarget'?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, shouldn't it be?

```
  self.feedbackTarget = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(FeedbackTarget)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.feedbackTarget = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:FeedbackTarget];
```

The object sent to `OCMockObject` here is something called `FeedbackTarget`.  But there is no object "FeedbackTarget".  That's the name of a protocol, to be sure, but it's not an object.

As Odrakir points out, you need to pass @protocol(FeedbackTarget).  Similarly, when passing a selector to an object, you pass @selector(theSelector: not the naked selector.